CKAN 2.10 source installation fails, missing folders
I tried to install CKAN 2.10 on Ubuntu 22.04 following the instruction in the guide but runing CKAN fails, I receive python error message "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/ckan' " and when I compare to a successful installation from "package" I can see that folder /var/lib/ckan is missing.
I do the installation on a remote Ubuntu server accessing via SSH and I have updated the ckan.ini file to reflect the new host address. Checking with ckan.ini user list I can see that the default user is created
Any suggesting for what can be wrong?
I have updated the ckan.ini file to reflect the remote host installation and carefully compared with a package installation on a remote host without
`
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 324, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 313, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware/flask_app.py", line 82, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware/common_middleware.py", line 87, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/beaker/middleware.py", line 156, in __call__
    return self.wrap_app(environ, session_start_response)
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware/common_middleware.py", line 31, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1440, in handle_exception
    server_error = self.ensure_sync(handler)(server_error)
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware/flask_app.py", line 624, in error_handler
    return base.render(
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/base.py", line 107, in render
    return flask_render_template(template_name, **extra_vars)
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 147, in render_template
    return _render(
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 128, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1301, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 936, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/error_document_template.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "page.html" %}
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckanext/activity/templates/page.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% ckan_extends %}
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/page.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "base.html" %}
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckanext/activity/templates/base.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% ckan_extends %}
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/base.html", line 71, in top-level template code
    {%- block styles %}
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckanext/activity/templates/base.html", line 4, in block 'styles'
    {{ super() }}
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/base.html", line 74, in block 'styles'
    {% asset theme %}
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/jinja_extensions.py", line 338, in _call
    h.include_asset(args[0])
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/webassets_tools.py", line 112, in include_asset
    urls = [url_for_static_or_external(url) for url in bundle.urls()]
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webassets/bundle.py", line 833, in urls
    urls.extend(bundle._urls(new_ctx, extra_filters, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webassets/bundle.py", line 767, in _urls
    self._build(ctx, extra_filters=extra_filters, force=False,
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webassets/bundle.py", line 609, in _build
    update_needed = ctx.updater.needs_rebuild(self, ctx) \
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webassets/updater.py", line 173, in needs_rebuild
    super(TimestampUpdater, self).needs_rebuild(bundle, ctx) or \
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webassets/updater.py", line 103, in needs_rebuild
    return self.check_bundle_definition(bundle, ctx)
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webassets/updater.py", line 82, in check_bundle_definition
    if not ctx.cache:
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webassets/bundle.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    return self.getattr(self._parent, item)
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webassets/bundle.py", line 58, in getattr
    return getattr(object, item)
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webassets/env.py", line 509, in _get_cache
    cache = get_cache(self._storage['cache'], self)
  File "/home/alkragh/ckan/lib/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/webassets/cache.py", line 236, in get_cache
    os.makedirs(directory)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/ckan'
`


The "PermissionError" indicates incorrect ownership of the /var/lib/ckan directory. To fix this, change the ownership to the user under which your CKAN instance runs. For example, if you’re running CKAN with Nginx, the Nginx user (typically www-data on Ubuntu) must have read, write, and execute permissions for the /var/lib/ckan. You can set this up with the following commands:
sudo chown www-data /var/lib/ckan
sudo chmod u+rwx /var/lib/ckan

This should resolve the permission issues by ensuring the correct user has full access to the directory.

Thank you for proposal. I tested it and get same result. I will go for the Docker installation.
